# SQL deleting records with group by multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-delete

I am trying to delete duplicate records in a table but on if they are duplicate per a record from another.

The following query gets me the number of duplicate records per 'bodyshop'.
Im trying to delete multiple invoices for each bodyshop.

```
SELECT
    inv.InvoiceNo, job.BodyshopId, COUNT(*)
FROM
    [Test].[dbo].[Invoices] as inv
  join [Test].[dbo].Repairs as rep on rep.Id = inv.RepairId
  join [Test].[dbo].Jobs as job on job.Id = rep.JobsId
GROUP BY
    inv.InvoiceNo, job.BodyshopId
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

I want the duplicate invoice numbers per bodyshop to be deleted but i do want the original one to remain.

```
InvoiceNo   BodyshopId  (No column name)
29737        16          2
29987        16          3
30059        16          2
23491        139         2
23608        139         3
23867        139         4
23952        139         3
```

I only want invoice number 29737 to be once against bodyshopid 16 etc.

Hope that makes sense

Thanks

Comment: How do you know which row is "original"?Look into `ROW_NUMBER() OVER PARTITION BY..`

Comment: You don't really but right now it doesn't matter. There is a created on date field on the invoice table which we could use to say the latest or the oldest is the original but not fussed really as the values are the same in the records

Comment: @Beginner:I think the min(`InvoiceNo`) could be the original?

Comment: May be original was the wrong word to use. I just want one of the invoices to remain against that bodyshop from the duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this :

```
with cte as (
SELECT
    inv.ID, inv.InvoiceNo, job.BodyshopId, rn = row_number() over (partition by inv.InvoiceNo, job.BodyshopId order by inv.InvoiceNo, job.BodyshopId)
FROM
    [Test].[dbo].[Invoices] as inv
  join [Test].[dbo].Repairs as rep on rep.Id = inv.RepairId
  join [Test].[dbo].Jobs as job on job.Id = rep.JobsId
)

delete t1
from [Test].[dbo].[Invoices] t1 inner join cte t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID 
where t2.rn > 1
```

Edit 1 - Your comments are trues. So a solution is to add an identity column to the invoice table. I've adapt my query.

To add / remove an identity column :

```
 alter table [Test].[dbo].[Invoices]  id int identity(1,1)
 drop  column id
```

Comment: View or function 'cte' is not updatable because the modification affects multiple base tables. - I get this message

Comment: also would this not delete all of the duplicate invoices? now living at least one?

Answer (score 0):

You may run the following as two records are same so, `Group by` will return single row for same invoice:

```
DELETE FROM inv where id not in (
SELECT Max(inv.id) FROM (
SELECT
    inv.id, inv.InvoiceNo, job.BodyshopId, COUNT(*)
FROM
    [Test].[dbo].[Invoices] as inv
  join [Test].[dbo].Repairs as rep on rep.Id = inv.RepairId
  join [Test].[dbo].Jobs as job on job.Id = rep.JobsId
GROUP BY
    inv.InvoiceNo, job.BodyshopId
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
) TMP_TABLE )
```

*id is the primary key.*

*General SQL. Modify if needed for sql-server.*

Comment: Would this not delete all other invoices in the table that do not have duplicates?

Comment: Really i think we should group by and then select the max invoice id then delete that, and then repeat again so delete one duplicate at a time. If a invoice doesnt have a duplicate it wont appear in the statement so wont get deleted